# storyboard! vs. UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

Tags: ios, swift

I got put into a project that has the following declaration:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("asdf") as! AsdfViewController
```

I've always used `storyboard!` to do this. It is my understanding that `storyboard!` will always give me `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`. Is this a dangerous assumption to make?

I know that you may want to use the official constructor for `UIStoryboard` if you wanted to reference a different storyboard file, but is it safe to abbreviate it to `storyboard!` if you are sure that the VC you wish to instantiate is part of `Main.storyboard`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling `self.storyboard` from a view controller that is on another storyboard file, it will give reference to that particular storyboard; not the main storyboard. By mentioning:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

You can make sure that you are referencing the main storyboard always.

In following situations:

1. Have only one storyboard file
2. Instantiate a view controller which is also included in the current view controller's storyboard

using `self.storyboard` is enough.

Comment: Even if you only have one storyboard file `self.storyboard` might not be enough if you have view controllers that aren't created from the storyboard.

Comment: So if you use multiple storyboards, it's unwise to use `storyboard!`?

Comment: @KelvinLau: Personal opinion (may not be true). Use `self.storyboard` if you are extremely sure if you are calling from same storyboard. I ran into a problem recently: I started one of my project from single storyboard file. As the project became bigger, the size of main storyboard increased. So one day I started restructuring the main storyboard by adding new storyboard files and separating the view controllers from it. Do you know what happened next ? The whole application got crashed each and every click due to `self.storyboard` calls.